# How can I free up a Google Cloud GPU quota after I removed a VM which had a GPU attached?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a quota for 1 GPU on Google Cloud. I had 1 VM running with a GPU attached. I deleted this VM but I am unable to create a new VM with a GPU as it says my quota of 1/1 GPU has been reached. How can I free up the quota now that I am not running any GPUs?

Comment: It SHOULD have freed it up...a support ticket to billing is probably the fastest way to get resolution on it I think?

Comment: Also, just to be sure, did you DELETE it, or just stop it? (I know you said delete, I'm just confirming the easy check. :) )

Comment: I deleted it :)

Comment: Just making sure. :) Yeah, it SHOULD (I asked my colleague who works with GCE primarily) have freed up the GPU quota we think. So like I mentioned, a ticket in to the billing team is likely the fastest way to dive in.

Comment: Your next step is to try to recreate the VM with GPU  at same location. As such it will tell you either there is a mistake on quota page or perhaps a resource exhaustion issue on GCP. (check logs at logging or at Home>activity.

Comment: @danyL - It turns out it was a resource exhaustion issue on GCP. My quota page however still shows that I am using 1 out of 1 GPUs. I'll keep trying to launch the VM to see if it will launch when GCP has resources available in the region.

Comment: **Daily quotas reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT)**, so it takes time to reset. Are you still facing issues? If yes, Can you provide information about the VM instance you are trying to create like Region,Zone,Instance configuration(GPU type,series,no. of GPU). Is the deleted VM still visible in the console?

Comment: @GoliNikitha - The issue has been resolved. My issue was not due to my quota. It was due to GCP not having enough resources in the region. I finally got a VM up and running by choosing a different GPU. What confused me was all the time I was going through this the quota page showed that my quota was full. Maybe it was just a UI issue

Comment: @HenryChinner Since your issue is resolved can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. My issue was not due to my quota. It was due to GCP not having enough resources in the region. I finally got a VM up and running by choosing a different GPU. What confused me was all the time I was going through this the quota page showed that my quota was full. Maybe it was just a UI issue.